# How to Display the items in listbox in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

please tell me how to show alphabets at the right most of list whenever click on particular alphabet i need to show that starting words.

tell me how to acheive this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is very iOS-like. The more appropriate experience for WP is the same as the contacts list uses (and application list if it's long enough), whereby each "group" contains a header icon above it and tapping that icon provides a selection of all of the group headers (letters in your case).

The `LongListSelector` control that ships as part of the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) does all the legwork for you, you just need to supply it with a list of groups. For your case, I'm sure `OriginalList.GroupBy(x => x.Name[0])` would be sufficient for `ListListSelector.ItemsSource`.